# JSP dropdown, shortening results

Tags: database, forms, jsp, model-view-controller

So im trying to populate a dropdown with entries from a specific database. Right nwo it works, however it puts in the ENTIRE entry which has 10+ attributes, where i only need a couple of them. Is there any way to specify which columns get passed back and displayed in the dropdown?

```
<tr>
<TD><span class="required">*</span> CMS Group ID:</TD>
<td><form:select path="cmsGroupId">
<form:options items="${list}" itemValue="id" /> 
</form:select>
</td>
<td><form:errors path="cmsGroupId" cssClass="required" /></td>
</tr>
```

Ideally id like to only get the first 4 columns from here. (ID, Version, Name, Entity ID) but dont really know how to make it work. Ive found bits on doing a c:foreach loop but havent gotten that working right either...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Build the appropriate display values on the Java side, not in JSP.

Don't try to do this in the view layer–IMO it's not the right place for such logic.

Comment: Hmm, im rather new to this so please pardon what im sure are rookie mistakes im making :) Re-wrote my getters to only retrieve the columns i need and then return them, however the dropdown entry still shows the 'other' attributes as =null now.

Comment: public List<CmsGroup> getCmsGroupList() {
List<CmsGroup> cmsGroupList = jdbcTemplate.query(SELECT_CMS_LIST, new RowMapper<CmsGroup>() {
public CmsGroup mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
CmsGroup obj = new CmsGroup();
obj.setId(rs.getInt("Id"));   obj.setVersion(rs.getInt("Version"));
obj.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
return obj;}});
return cmsGroupList;}